# jQuery scroll to div won't scroll, only jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked before but I can't make it work, no matter how many links and demos I've tried in the answers.

Please take a look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container container-fluid hiimorsi">

<a href="#about"><img src="img/arrow-211-64.png" class=" d-block img-fluid"></a>
</div>
</div>

 <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
```

My jQuery snippet (current one)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#arrow").on("click", function (e) {
        document.querySelector('.hello').scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see I am using bootstrap (for the first time), wondering whether maybe that is messing with the code?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you including jQuery twice?

Comment: Is that your full html? Can't see `.hello` element.

Comment: why are you using ` document.querySelector('.hello')` instead of the jQuery's selector?

Comment: Sorry, not the full code. I have created a fiddler with the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/7cnpbr83/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you put `#` as your href value.

```
<a href="#about">
 <img src="img/arrow-211-64.png" class=" d-block img-fluid">
</a>
```

What happens is, it would jump to the top of the browser when clicked.

Change that to:

```
<a>
  <img src="img/arrow-211-64.png" class=" d-block img-fluid">
</a>
```

Comment: #about refers to a div with an id "about" - am I wrong to use that??

Comment: @Orsi Well in your case since you want to have a smooth scroll then it's not right to use `#about`. If you click on an element with an href `#about` it will immediately jump to that element.

Answer (score 0):

why not use the jquery animation effect.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(){
            $("#arrow").on("click", function (e) {
                let scrollToPos = document.querySelector('.hello').offsetTop;
                $('body').animate({scrollTop: scrollToPos },500,'linear');

            });
      })();
    </script>
```

not sure but believe that the `scrollIntoView` native effect does not have any animation / easing on it but it's job is to natively jump to that item. Butdont quote me on that :-)

Comment: I have just tried this and it still doesn't work - it jumps to the specific section as opposed to slowly scrolling down to it. Can you maybe take a look at it in fiddler? https://jsfiddle.net/7cnpbr83/ thanks in advance.

Comment: you might need jquery easing as well?? but will have quick look :-)

Comment: nothign to click on there and if i click the funny link i get a modal pop up nothing to scroll???

Comment: The arrow image is supposed to be under the quote (the Britney quote is a joke, hope thats clear), it doesn't appear because I didn't upload the image to fiddler. If you hover over it, you can see that it's linked to #about which is the first card (Why growth tribe), it has the id "about"

Comment: i think its cause your using the hash way and it overriding, but any way here is a simple codepen example. http://codepen.io/simondavies/pen/WRXOZw